# Удаление объектов с связями между собой

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Суть вопроса. Не могу придумать адекватный подход удаления. В моей ситуации имеются сущности допустим коробка. В коробке могут лежать ещё коробки и тд. В одной коробке может лежать несколько, а в них ещё и тд. Как корректно удалить все. Если к примеру я удаляю самую первую коробку, в которой может лежать N коробок, в которых ещё могут лежать и тд. Все коробки лежат в `List<Box>`. Пользователь вводит имя коробки, которую необходимо удалить. И нужно удалить все коробки, которые лежат внутри.

```
public class Box
{
    public string NameBox{get;set;}

    public string RootNameBox{get;set;}
}
```

Привел пример класса, которые реализует эту зависимость.

Comment: Удалить откуда?

Comment: @4per, удалить все объекты с возможными связями между собой. Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас нет какой либо связанности между объектами (что зря), то ваш алгоритм должен быть примерно такой:

- Берем нужную коробку на удаление.
- Отдаем ее методу удаления.

  - Метод удаления ищет коробку/коробки, которые ссылаются на эту коробку удаления и рекурсивно вызывает самого себя.

Простой пример подобной реализации:

- Ваш класс коробки (я добавил лишь конструктор)

  ```
  public class Box
  {
      public Box(string name, string rootBox = default)
      {
          NameBox = name;
          RootNameBox = rootBox;
      }

      public string NameBox { get; set; }

      public string RootNameBox { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Глобальный список всех коробок (если он не глобальный, то скорей всего придется передавать в метод параметром.

  ```
  static List<Box> boxes = new List<Box>
      {
          new Box("box1"),
          new Box("box2", "box1"),
          new Box("box3", "box2"),
          new Box("box4")
      };
  ```
- Некий метод удаления (набросал его быстро, чисто показать пример подобного, если в 1 коробке может быть несколько коробок, то берите не первую, а все найденные и прогоняйте их циклом через метод.

  ```
  static void Delete(Box box)
  {
      var rootBox = boxes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RootNameBox == box.NameBox);
      if (rootBox != null)
      {
          Delete(rootBox);
      }

      boxes.Remove(box);
  }
  ```
- Ну и вызов.

  ```
  var firstBox = boxes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NameBox == "box1");
  Delete(firstBox);
  ```

Имея все это, мы можем приукрасить все и сделать например метод расширения:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void DeleteBox(this List<Box> boxes, string boxName)
    {
        DeleteBox(boxes, boxes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NameBox == boxName));
    }

    public static void DeleteBox(this List<Box> boxes, Box box)
    {
        if (box == null) return;

        var rootBox = boxes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RootNameBox == box.NameBox);
        if (rootBox != null)
        {
            boxes.DeleteBox(rootBox);
        }

        boxes.Remove(box);
    }
}
```

Тогда вызов будет вообще:

```
boxes.DeleteBox("box1");
```

В общем саму суть рекурсии вы поняли, дальше сами дорабатывайте как вам надо. Удачи!

---

> А что ты говорил про связи? Не мог бы подробнее?

Сейчас вы совершенно не знаете что за коробка у вас например будет в `box1`, ибо только `box2` знает о том, что у нее есть "предок". На мой взгляд правильней будет переписать класс коробки на нечто подобное:

```
public class Box
{
    public Box(string name, Box rootBox = default)
    {
        NameBox = name;
        RootBox = rootBox;
    }

    public string NameBox { get; set; }

    public Box RootBox { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь основная коробка знает о том, что у нее есть дочерняя коробка и так у вас уже выстраивается цепочка зависимостей (`box1.RootBox.RootBox.RootBox...`).

И тогда нам уже не надо будет искать объект по имени, нам достаточно взять нужную коробку и удалить ее:

```
static void Delete(Box box)
{
    if (box.RootBox != null)
        Delete(box.RootBox);

    boxes.Remove(box);
}
```

Инициализация тут будет тогда примерно следующая:

```
var box4 = new Box("box4");
var box3 = new Box("box3");
var box2 = new Box("box2", box3);
var box1 = new Box("box1", box2);

boxes = new List<Box> { box1, box2, box3, box4 };
```

- `box1` ссылается на `box2`.
- `box2` ссылается на `box3`.
- `box3` и `box4` являются простыми коробками, без ссылок.

Вызываем метод удаления для удаления первой коробки:

```
Delete(box1);
```

и в результате у нас останется только `box4`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Протестирую. А что ты говорил про связи? Не мог бы подробнее?

Comment: @Valera Сейчас вы в классе храните имя на объект, что дает вам мало информации о нем и возможностей. В C# классы являются ссылочными типами, а значит вы можете хранить не имя, а ссылку на вложенную коробку (`public Box RootBox { get; set; }`), это уже как минимум уберет необходимость поиска объекта по имени.

Comment: спасибо, за развёрнутый ответ

Comment: @Valera Я дописал вам про ссылки. Если ответ вас устраивает, то не забудьте его принять (галка сборку от ответа).

Comment: В первом случае я бы еще учёл возможные циклы

Comment: @tym32167 в плане?

Comment: @Valera если вставить коробку А в коробку Б, а после вставить коробку Б в А

Comment: @tym32167 это не возможно)

Comment: @Valera я тоже так когда то думал про мою похожую задачу

Comment: @tym32167 если я столкнусь с этим я тебе обязательно скажу)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы реализовали задачу обратную от того что просил ТС. Нужно было вместе с главной коробкой удалить всё то, что в ней лежит.

Comment: @4per И что я сделал не так?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, если `rootBox` - это дочерняя коробка, и она всегда одна, то всё нормально.

Comment: @4per В моем примере есть 2 коробки `box1` и `box4`, в коробке `box1` есть `box2`, которая содержит в себе еще и `box3` (пример подразумевает единственную вложенность (об этом я говорил в ответе)). Мы удаляем `box1`, а значит удаляем и все то, что "в ней" (`box2` и `box3`). После работы кода, получаем массив с 1 коробкой - `box4`. Так что я без понятия о какой "обратной реализации" тут идет речь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, вы меня запутали терминологией, мне тяжело было понять, что у вас `root` - это коробка внутри, а не снаружи.

Comment: @4per Класс `Box` не мой, взял из вопроса. От сюда и пошли эти `root`, ибо так понятней думаю автору вопроса.